# The set of all sections of a frame bundle

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth
vector bundle of rank $n$ and $\pi_{F} : FE \to M$ be associated frame bundle to $E$.

The set of all sections of a frame bundle is not a vector space, why?

Why is it a topological space?

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

That set is a subset of the set of all continuous maps $M\to FE$. The latter is a topological space (in several ways: consult a good general topology textbook) so the formar inherits a topology.

As for why this set is not a vector space... How do you propose to add two sections?